# Model validation complex types in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a mvc view which comsumes a model in the model I have a userinformation object which contains data about the current user and some other properties used in a form.

when I submit the form the simple types are mapped correctly and the validation works fine, but the complex type is set to null, so if the validation fails and I show the view again that userinformation object is null and the data is not shown , even though I don't use it as part of the form.

```
public class AssessorsViewModel
{
     public UserInfo UserInformation { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an assessment provider")]
    [Display(Name = "Assessor Provider Name")]
    public string Assessor { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the type of assessment")]
    [Display(Name = "Assessment Type")]
    public byte AssessmentType { get; set; }


}
```

How can I persist this user information on form submission? I tried adding the object to a hidden field but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide your html file?

Without that file I am assuming that you are not putting the UserInfo properties in the form.  In order for the value to be posted with the form, it needs to be in the form.  To do this, put hidden fields in your form for each of the UserInfo properties.

Razor:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
```

I would suggest considering putting the UserInfo data into a cookie.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the case.